# Execute code block in nested regex only if the whole match succeeded in Perl 6

Tags: regex, raku

I would like a code block within a nested `regex` to be executed *only* if the whole pattern matches.

Here's my test code.

```perl6
my regex left {
    | a  { take "left: 'a' matched" }
    | aa { take "left: 'aa' matched" }
}
my regex right { b }
my regex whole {
    ^
    <left>
    <right>
    $
}

my $string = 'aab';
my @left_history = gather
      $string ~~ m:ex/ <whole> /;

.say for @left_history;
```

As expected, it produces the following output:

```perl6
left: 'aa' matched
left: 'a' matched
```

But I want it to print only the 1st line, corresponding to the value of `left`, which was used in the successful match. Is it possible?

(Of course, I understand that I can extract the successful values of `<left>` from the `$/` match variable)

UPD: In general, `:ex` or `:g` produce many matches, so I'd like the code block in the nested regex to be executed during *each* successful match of the whole pattern.

Comment: I have to run but a quick note. Aiui the point of the `:ex` matching option is to try to match all alternations rather than just pick a winner. Thus switching to, say, `my regex left { [ | a | aa ] { take "left: $/ matched" } }`, which only `take`s whichever successfully matched, still prints both because `:ex` tells the regex engine to keep trying to match all alternations.

Comment: @raiph I think the same, so I wonder whether there is some solution.

Comment: "I wonder whether there is some solution." Can you explain why simply removing the `:ex` is not a solution?

Comment: @raiph, of course. This program is a simplified test to show the problems which I encounter with my real-life data. And there I usually have to get all the matches, so I use `:ex`. It's possible (and most likely) that what I'm doing is in no way optimal, but in general I want the alternative of a nested `regex` that matched during every successful match to give me some specific info about itself. If there is no good solution, maybe I should rather analyze the `$/` directly...

Comment: You are right, using "successful match" in singular may be misleading, I'll edit the post.

Comment: @raiph I've finally got it with your kind help and made an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47091611/7730888)

Comment: I think your answer was spot on. I've deleted my answer because in revisiting it now I see I hadn't understood your question, solved the wrong thing, had bugs in my solution, had nothing of interest in it, then misunderstood your comments on it and had bugs in my comments! Even your comments just reflected confusion I'd created, not valuable insight. So, I deleted it. In the meantime my comments above are also mostly missing the point and/or confusing. I think you essentially figured this out yourself with me mostly serving as a rubber duck. :)

Comment: I think a simple fix is to use `token` rather than `regex`

Answer (score 3):

The following modification of the program is based on @raiph's very useful explanations. It's not an entirely general answer to the original question, but it solves my problems, so I venture to post it as an answer. Any corrections and improvements are very welcome!

```perl6
my regex left {
    | a   { $*left_history = "left: 'a' matched" }
    | aa  { $*left_history = "left: 'aa' matched" }
    | aab { $*left_history = "left: 'aab' matched" }
}
my regex right { b }
my regex whole {
    :my $*left_history;
    ^
    <left>
    <right>
    $
    { take $*left_history }
}

my $string = 'aab';
my @left_history = gather
      $string ~~ m:ex/ <whole> /;

.say for @left_history;
```

Output:

```perl6
left: 'aa' matched
```

It would be better if the scope of the variable would be restricted to `whole` and `left`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: "It would be better if the scope of the variable would be restricted to whole and left, but I don't know how to do it." The obvious solution -- using a lexical local to `whole` and passing it as an argument to `left` -- doesn't work due to a bug in Rakudo which looks like [this bug report about backtracking over calls with arguments resulting in "expected X but got Y argument" errors](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130910).

Comment: Just visiting this SO and caught Brad Gilbert's amazingly simple suggestion in a comment on your question. "I think a simple fix is to use `token` rather than `regex` – Brad Gilbert Jul 25 '18 at 20:57" Sure enough, just changing `my regex left` to `my token left` in the example code in your question gets the result you say you were looking for!